# How to extract the redirected link that loads after 30 seconds?

Tags: python, url, xpath

When I click the download button of the website. It tells to wait for the 30 to load and redirects to the google drive. I want to get directly the link(redirected link)

---

https://www.engineerrefe.com/2019/05/protection-of-industrial-power.html

This is the website where there is download button.

Link location of download button.

[https://www.engineerrefe.com/p/redirect.html??&&url=*https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wIhS0QPuyEOWZrSnP0wtKHTWGCpbely*](https://www.engineerrefe.com/p/redirect.html??&&url=_https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wIhS0QPuyEOWZrSnP0wtKHTWGCpbely_)

I tried (.url ) module for getting the redirecting link by copying the download link.

```py
import requests
#Link Location of Download button
page_contents = requests.get('https://www.engineerrefe.com/p/redirect.html??&&url=_https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wIhS0QPuyEOWZrSnP0wtKHTWGCpbely_')
print(page_contents.url)
# It prints the same.
```

Comment: It seems you already have the redirect link to Google drive in your URL. Why don't you simply extract it from there instead of doing a GET request?

Comment: I have more than  300 links :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have a set of links. If they all are in the same format as the example one you gave then, given that the links are in a file called `links.txt`, then you could use this function to take out only the google drive link:

```
import re

with open("links.txt", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read()

def getUrl():
    indexes = [x.start() for x in re.finditer("_", contents)]
    urloutput = ""

    for i in range(indexes[0], indexes[1]):
        urloutput += contents[i + 1]

    return(urloutput)
```

Depending on how the urls are formatted in the list you will want to modify this to iterate through each instance of the url and use the function each time.

Comment: Wow I think I have try this .

Comment: Ok, if you have any issues let me know, Also I would greatly appreciate it that if this works for you then you could mark my answer as the answer.